# Why is weight comparison transitive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, weight

Suppose I have a regular pair of weight-comparison scales sitting on my kitchen table, and three weights.

When I place A on either side and B on the other, the "B" side always goes down.

When I place B on either side and C on the other, the "C" side always goes down.

When I place C on either side and A on the other, the "A" side always goes down.

This would be a surprising violation physical intuition: we feel that weight-comparison should be transitive.

What formal physical principle or principles would we say this is violating? Why is this an unreasonable outcome to expect?

This question is **not** about what alteration might be made to the scales or the environment to cause this outcome. It is specifically about the law or set of laws which prohibits this kind of behaviour.

Comment: This would violate Newton's second law of motion, force equals mass times acceleration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this is a fun question.

The answer is that if weight is not transitive, you get to create a perpetual motion device!

To do this, you need to understand something about how elevators work, the motor in the elevator is actually not strong enough to lift up the elevator car by itself. Instead, the elevator is connected by a big steel cable to a pulley at the top, and the cable goes down the other side to a big counterweight, and the counterweight weighs almost the exact same as the elevator car. Because the two balance each other out, the motor can be much cheaper, it only needs to be able to lift the passengers and not the whole steel contraption because that is already accounted for by the pulley and the cable being strong enough to transfer this counterweight’s force without breaking.

So the observation is, if you have a pulley and two things which have equal weight, then it is almost effortless to move one up while the other comes down along the pulley.

So if X equals Y and Y equals Z but X is heavier than Z, you can

1. use a pulley loaded with X and Y to raise X one floor while lowering Y one floor, then
2. load the pulley with Y and Z to lower Z one floor while  raising Y back where it started, and finally,
3. load the pulley with X and Z plus some extra load which you want to lift, and since X is heavier than Z you can lift at least some small amount of extra load up one floor while X and Z return to where they came from.

So all of the three things return back to their starting positions but some extra work is done, the definition of a perpetual motion cycle. So the thing that is expected is not weight-specific; it is a transitivity of *all forces*: forces cannot have “different kinds” whose equality is intransitive, for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it indicates that either your scales do not compare weight, or that "weight" does not exist. Because if such thing as "weight" exist  (i.e. each system can be characterized by a corresponding real number) and your scales compare it between different objects, then, due to the "weight" being a real number, the comparison must be transitive.

Comment: What physical law or laws prohibit this outcome?

Comment: I have no idea if there is any "law" associated with it. I doubt anyone bothered to question that weight exist to make a law for it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand this question completely.

You are asking why weight comparison has to be transitive.

Is this not trivial ?

Weight refers to the force of gravity exerted by the earth on the object.
So, if B is heavier than A, it means magnitude of force exerted on B is greater than that on A.

Similarly, if C is heavier than B, it means magnitude of force exerted on B is greater than that on A.

So, by simple maths, it has to be the case that  C will be heavier than A.

What am i missing here ? Do you mean something else than what i am saying ?

Answer (score 0):

Weight has nothing to do with the principle, which holds true of any other physical quantity. If stick B is longer than stick A, and stick C is longer than stick B, then stick C is longer than stick A. If box A will fit inside box B, and box B will fit inside box C, box C will not fit inside box A. The laws of mathematics prohibit the possibility that a<b, b<c, c<a where a,b,c are numbers.

Comment: You make the assumption that weight (as opposed to the weights mentioned in the question) is a quantity. Note that this is not a claim directly verified by experiment, but rather a consequence of experimental confirmation that the axioms of ordered sets apply to weights and scales (specifically, with the order being weight comparison on scales), one of which is transitivity. The question regards whether there is some more general law that would allow this to be inferred without prior experience of weights and scales specifically.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. In what sense is weight in my assumption apposed to the weights in your question? Why is it an assumption that weight can be quantified? What is the meaning of 'this' in your second sentence? I fail to see see how any law could allow you to infer properties of weights and scales if you were not aware of weights and scales.